# Celery losing bootstep after recovering RabbitMQ connection

Tags: python, celery

I have an application in Python using celery connected to RabbitMQ.
I'm adding a bootstep, if celery loses connection to RabbitMQ, starts retrying to connect, but after it reconnect successfully it stops running the bootstep configured. I haven't found a way to get it working back once the reconnection is done.

I haven't found a way to get it working back once the reconnection is done.

```
from celery import Celery
from my_module import TestBootstep

app = Celery()
app.steps["worker"].add(TestBootstep)
app.config_from_object("my_module.config.celeryconfig")
app.start()
```

```
class TestBootstep(bootsteps.StartStopStep):
    requires = {'celery.worker.components:Timer'}

    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.tref = None

    def start(self, parent):
        print("I'm starting")
        self.tref = parent.timer.call_repeatedly(
            5.0, self.test, (parent,), priority=10,
        )

    def stop(self, parent):
        print("I'm finished")

    def test(self, parent):
        print("I'm logging")
```